# Integrate socket.io into angular-seed web-server.js

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I downloaded the Angular project [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), and was using the node web-server.js file they provided to run my code.

I already built out enough functionality that it would be non-trivial to switch to another project and re-do the URL handling already managed in web-server.js.

I want to add socket.io to my stack. However, the way socket.io is (by default) added to the client stack is a line that looks like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Because of the web-server.js URL rewrites, this doesn't work. What do I do?

I already have installed node.js, npm, and socket.io

Answer (score 2):

socket.io.js on client code is served dynamically by node (it's not a resource). However, this web-server does url rewriting, so you can't use it as normal:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but instead you need to serve it like so:

```
<script src="http://nodeJS_server:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

where, for testing, `nodeJS_server` is probably `localhost`

and `port` is what you define for socket.io, and not node itself. For example, in your dependencies at the top of web-server.js, if you added

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(8080),
```

That is creating a new server on port 8080 to handle your socket communication. So you would define your socket.io.js file in index.html as:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Hope this saves someone else a bit of time.